# CATIA VB.net create chanfer by selected face

Tags: vb.net, catia

I'm trying to create a chamfer using pre selected faces in a macro. But i'm no having much sucess

what I have tried:

The faces are previously selected.

```
chamfer2 = shapeFactory1.AddNewChamfer(reference1, catTangencyChamfer, catLengthAngleChamfer, catNoReverseChamfer, 1, 45.0#)
        Dim Num_Faces As Integer = selection1.count
        Dim Faces_ref(Num_Faces)
        For i = 1 To Num_Faces


            Dim MyBRepName = (selection1.Item(i).Value.Name)

            MyBRepName = Replace(MyBRepName, "Selection_", "")
            MyBRepName = Left(MyBRepName, InStrRev(MyBRepName, "));"))
            MyBRepName = MyBRepName + ");WithPermanentBody;WithoutBuildError;WithSelectingFeatureSupport;MFBRepVersion_CXR15)"

            MsgBox(MyBRepName)
            reference1 = Part1.CreateReferenceFromName(MyBRepName)

            chamfer1.AddElementToChamfer(reference1)

        Next
```

the error appears here:

chamfer1.AddElementToChamfer(reference1)

Comment: It seems like it should work.  What is the error message?

Comment: i Found my mistake... I add the chamfer with variable chamfer2, and I had the references to Chamfer1... It can't work like this...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove brackets from `reference1` like this:

```
chamfer1.AddElementToChamfer reference1
```